# How to add nested array of objects with @Prop decorator from @nestjs/mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose, nestjs, typescript-decorator, nestjs-mongoose

When I use a nested array of object in prop decorator:

```
@Schema()
export class Child {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
}
    
@Schema()
export class Parent {
  @Prop({type: [Child], _id: false}) // don't need `_id` for nested objects
  children: Child[];
}

export const ParentSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Parent);
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `Child` is not a valid type within the array `children`.
```

How can I fix this if I need to use `@Prop({_id: false})` (to keep the nested schema independent)?

---

If we change a prop decorator to `@Prop([Child])` it works, however we need to disable `_id` for nested object with:

```
@Schema({_id: false})
export class Child {
  @Prop()
  name: string;
}

@Schema()
export class Parent {
  @Prop([Child])
  children: Child[];
}
```

And in this case we won't have generic Child object and we won't to use them as an independent Schema.

Another way is to create `Child` schema and use it in `@Prop({type: [childSchema], _id: false})`, but that looks like an overhead.

Answer (score 5):

a quik example that describe your case is:

```
import { Document, Schema as MongooseSchema } from 'mongoose';
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

class GuildMember {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true, lowercase: true })
  _id: string;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  id: number;

  @Prop({ required: true })
  rank: number;
}

@Schema({ timestamps: true })
export class Guild extends Document {
  @Prop({ type: String, required: true, lowercase: true })
  _id: string;

  @Prop({ type: MongooseSchema.Types.Array})
  members: GuildMember[]
}

export const GuildsSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Guild);
```

because in nested schema you don't have yo define type INSIDE the prop decorator but only tell that this field is an array and validate the type using TypeScript